# TypeError solutions

Tags: python

Trying to run this code with some data and keeps giving the error. Any ideas about how to fix that? Thanks in advance:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

#Import our historical data
data = pd.read_csv('Data/EURUSD.csv')
data.columns = [['Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
data = data.set_index(data.Date)
data = data[['open', 'high', 'close', 'vol']]

price = data.close.iloc[:100]

# Find our relative extrema
max_idx = argrelextrema(price.values,np.greater,order=1)
min_idx = argrelextrema(price.values,np.less,order=1)

print(max_idx)
print(min_idx)
```

https://pastebin.com/sKqq2PgD

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: It's probably the ```data.set_index(data.Date)```. Can you post a line of raw csv data, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

The way you access the fields are incorrect.

e.g. Instead of

```
pd.to_datetime(data.Date,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

you should

```
 pd.to_datetime(data.iloc(0)[0].Date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

As a sidenote: the data you posted in pastebin is tab delimited. Your code in the question should be changed to `data = pd.read_csv('Data/EURUSD.csv', sep='\t')`

Comment: What do you mean with delimited?